# Problems with diagnostics of prophet forecast

Tags: dataset, forecast, train-test-split, facebook-prophet

I am working with an dataset of crimes in chicago and specially working on a future prediction of the crime rate in chicago (from 2012 till 2016 I have data). I generated a forecast using the prophet package of facebook. It worked very well and all done. Now I would like to train and test my model. Therefore, I split the dataset into 70% train and 30% test. I trained the model and test it and at the end I got a nice plot. I am further interested in the diagnostic part. Prophet provides for that a function called `cross_validation()` which I used: `df.cv<- cross_validation(m, initial = nrow(trainData), period = 365, horizon = nrow(testData), units = 'days')`
. The problems is here, I am geting always this error and trying since yesterday to fix it, without success:

```
Fehler in generate_cutoffs(df, horizon.dt, initial.dt, period.dt) : 
Less data than horizon after initial window. Make horizon or initial shorter.
```

Does somebody know how to fix this error and provide a list of diagnostics?

My train/test plot looks so:

[image: Train/Test Plot]

And my train Dataset can be downloaded here: https://ufile.io/4e38c
And my test Dataset here: https://ufile.io/ds65p

I hope somebody could help me! It would be really great and I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Cross-validation will be applied on a sliding window, performing cutoffs based on the settings. Please read the docs here:
https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/diagnostics.html

The error you get because your sliding window is out of bounds. Try like this:

```r
df.cv<- cross_validation(m, initial = 100, period = 100, horizon = 100, units = 'days')
```

Comment: You can also check the source code of these two functions here https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/R/R/diagnostics.R. I also found the discussion here https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/483 very useful to understand the diagnostic utilities better

Comment: The cut off has the size of 100 days (defined by horizon=100), right? What is the period?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and I managed to fix it by using **string** arguments such as `horizon="365 days"` , instead of **int** `horizon = 365`.

This solution worked on Python version.

Comment: His example is in R not in Python. In Python you have `horizon="365 days"` while in R you have `horizon=365`.

Comment: Life saver answer, thank you.